# MySQL: looking to SUM these UNIONs together

Tags: mysql, database, union

OK, my head hurts...!

This beautiful MySQL query:

```
(SELECT mtwitterfollowers AS twitfollow FROM `media` WHERE media.id=1)
UNION
(SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE peoplejoin.media_id = 1)
UNION 
(SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN networkjoin ON networkjoin.network_id = peoplejoin.network_id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE networkjoin.media_id = 1)
```

...returns three rows of pretty numbers.

Ideally, I'd like this query to return all three "twitfollow" results, SUMmed together.

However, putting a SUM round them gives me an error about "every derived table must have its own alias", and I'm a little confused as to quite how to do solve that.

(Of course, I could just sum the results in PHP; but I am assuming that it's quicker to do this using the MySQL server. Would I be right?)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use your entire query as the `FROM` clause of another query:

```
SELECT SUM(twitfollow) FROM (
    (SELECT mtwitterfollowers AS twitfollow FROM `media` WHERE media.id=1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE peoplejoin.media_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN networkjoin ON networkjoin.network_id = peoplejoin.network_id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE networkjoin.media_id = 1)
) t1
```

I also changed your `UNION` to `UNION ALL` as you probably don't want to remove rows just because the sum from one table is equal to the sum from another table.

Comment: Aha. The "t1" seems to do the trick. Many thanks, Dan. (The UNION ALL - yes, I need to look at what the two queries return.)

Comment: Yeah, you have to give the derived table you're selecting from a name, even if you don't use the name... that's all the `t1` is.

Answer (score 1):

Why not making it shorter, like below?

```
SELECT SUM(
    (SELECT mtwitterfollowers AS twitfollow FROM `media` WHERE media.id=1)
    +
    (SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE peoplejoin.media_id = 1)
    +
    (SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN networkjoin ON networkjoin.network_id = peoplejoin.network_id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE networkjoin.media_id = 1)
) AS twitterfollowers
```

Comment: There's no need for the `SUM` at all here since you're doing the addition manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a aggregating query around it:

```
SELECT SUM(twitfollow)
FROM
(
    (SELECT mtwitterfollowers AS twitfollow FROM `media` WHERE media.id=1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE peoplejoin.media_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(twitterfollowers) AS twitfollow FROM people LEFT JOIN peoplejoin ON peoplejoin.people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN networkjoin ON networkjoin.network_id = peoplejoin.network_id LEFT JOIN positions ON position_id = positions.id WHERE networkjoin.media_id = 1)
)
```

Comment: That's what I thought. However, that returns '#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias'.